# Calcular de suma no da resultado

Tags: javascript, condiciones, operador

Todas las operaciones funcionan, Pero por alguna razón la suma en vez de sumar se concatena. Está rarísimo. alguien cual es poblema?

```
var valor1 = prompt("Ingrese valor");
    
    var operacion = prompt("Operador:  +, -, *, / ?");
    
    var valor2 = prompt("Ingrese otro valor");
    
    
    var suma = "+";
    var resta = "-";
    var multiplica = "*";
    var division = "*";
    
    if (operacion == suma){ 
        calcularSuma = valor1 + valor2;
        alert(valor1 + '+' + valor2 +'='+ calcularSuma);
    } else if (operacion == resta){ 
        calcularResta = valor1 - valor2;
        alert(valor1 + '-' + valor2 +'='+ calcularResta);
    } else if (operacion == multiplica){ 
        calcularMulti = valor1 * valor2;
        alert(valor1 + '*' + valor2 +'='+ calcularMulti);
    } else if (operacion == division){ 
        calcularDivi = valor1 / valor2;
        alert(valor1 + '/' + valor2 +'='+ calcularDivi);
    }
```

introducir el código aquí

Comment: No es rarisimo.. para js, valor1 y valor2 son cadenas, y cuando haces + entre cadenas, estas se concatenan.. deberias transformarlas a numeros....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como menciona @gbianchi tus inputs siempre van a ser cadena, estas las tienes que convertir a numeros para poder realizar operaciones con ellos, por lo que agregando un `parseFloat()` para convertirlos a numeros, y aceptar numeros decimales, o usar `parseInt()` para obtener solamente el numero entero. Tendrias el resultado de

```
var valor1 = prompt("Ingrese valor");
    
    var operacion = prompt("Operador:  +, -, *, / ?");
    
    var valor2 = prompt("Ingrese otro valor");
    
    
    var suma = "+";
    var resta = "-";
    var multiplica = "*";
    var division = "*";
    
    if (operacion == suma){ 
        let calcularSuma = parseFloat(valor1) + parseFloat(valor2);
        alert(valor1 + '+' + valor2 +'='+ calcularSuma);
    } else if (operacion == resta){ 
        let calcularResta = parseFloat(valor1) - parseFloat(valor2);
        alert(valor1 + '-' + valor2 +'='+ calcularResta);
    } else if (operacion == multiplica){ 
        let calcularMulti = parseFloat(valor1) * parseFloat(valor2);
        alert(valor1 + '*' + valor2 +'='+ calcularMulti);
    } else if (operacion == division){ 
        let calcularDivi = parseFloat(valor1) / parseFloat(valor2);
        alert(valor1 + '/' + valor2 +'='+ calcularDivi);
    }
```

Espero te funcione, feliz día

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Viva México!

Comment: Soy de Guatemala, pero apoyo!